# Running Django + Postgresql + Gunicorn in Docker container using compose - file permission errors

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn, file-permissions

I am using Docker-desktop version version 20.10.16 on Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS

I want to Dockerise Django (v3.2), PostgreSQl (v14.3) and Gunicorn (v20.1.0) in a single container. And use those containers as Virtual hosts being serviced by a single Nginx instance that is running on my local machine.

I am able to build images, and a container, but setting up the django application fails, because of a file error in creating/writing to myporoj.log
I am currently, not using nginx as a proxy server to the virtual hosts - I want o resolve this isse first before moving on to using Nginx with my setup.

Here are additional relevant details:

My file structure (on local machine), is as follows:

```
/path/to/myprojectweb/
            /myproj
               /myproj
               settings.py 
               wsgi.py
               # etc.
           Dockerfile.prod
           compose.prod.yml
```

#### Dockerfile.prod.yml

```
# Builder Image

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster as Builder


WORKDIR /usr/src/app


ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWEITEBYTECODE 1


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev
  

RUN pip install --upgrade pip pipenv
COPY Pipfile* ./
RUN pipenv lock --keep-outdated --requirements > requirements.txt \
    && pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt


# Final Image

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN mkdir -p /home/app  /var/log/gunicorn

# create user + group app that apps will run as.
RUN groupadd -r app && useradd --no-log-init -r -g app app

ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt ./

RUN chown -R app:app $HOME
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME && chmod ug+rws $APP_HOME
RUN chown -R app:app /var/log/gunicorn

# change user before install, so 3rd party packages can be updated with makemigrations/migrate
USER app
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

COPY . $APP_HOME
```

#### compose.prod.yml

```
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:14.3

    restart: always
    container_name: myproj_postgres_db
    env_file:
      - .env

    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  # Gunicorn tips from: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/gunicorn-in-docker/
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    container_name: myproj_app
    restart: always
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate &&
             gunicorn --capture-output \
                      --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log  \
                      --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log  \
                      --enable-stdio-inheritance  \
                      --workers 3  \
                      --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm \
                      --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
                       myproj.wsgi:application" 
    #--bind unix:/var/log/gunicorn/myproj.sock 
    
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env

    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Here is the output (snippet) from the following command:

> /path/to/mypjo/$ sudo docker compose -f compose.prod.yml up --build

```
myproj_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
myproj_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 563, in configure
myproj_app          |     handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
myproj_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 744, in configure_handler
myproj_app          |     result = factory(**kwargs)
myproj_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/handlers.py", line 200, in __init__
myproj_app          |     BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, 'a', encoding, delay)
myproj_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/handlers.py", line 55, in __init__
myproj_app          |     logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
myproj_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1147, in __init__
myproj_app          |     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
myproj_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1176, in _open
myproj_app          |     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
myproj_app          | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/app/web/myproj.log'
myproj_app          | 
myproj_app          | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
myproj_app          | 
myproj_app          | Traceback (most recent call last):
myproj_app          |   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
myproj_app          |     main()
myproj_app          |   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
myproj_app          |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
myproj_app          |   File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
myproj_app          |     utility.execute()
myproj_app          |   File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
myproj_app          |     django.setup()
myproj_app          |   File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
myproj_app          |     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
myproj_app          |   File "/home/app/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
myproj_app          |     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
myproj_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
myproj_app          |     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
myproj_app          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 570, in configure
myproj_app          |     raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
myproj_app          | ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'logfile'
myproj_app          | sh: 3: --access-logfile: not found
myproj_app          | sh: 4: --error-logfile: not found
myproj_app          | sh: 5: --enable-stdio-inheritance: not found
myproj_app          | sh: 6: --workers: not found
myproj_app          | sh: 7: --worker-tmp-dir: not found
myproj_app          | sh: 8: --bind: not found
myproj_app          | sh: 9: myproj.wsgi:application: not found
myproj_app exited with code 127
```

So although I chmod permissions for required folders (even setting sticky flag where appropriate) - I still have file permission errors, and Gunicorn also barfs abut not finding `wsgi.py`

How do I fix the file error permission issue and also, get gunicorn to run (using the configuration data I am passing on to it through CL flags?)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari thanks, I'll try that - *BUT* i'm not sure that making the file world executable is a good idea, but I think it is a useful step to try to eliminate other potential causes.

Comment: Nope, the same errors are displayed as above. So it is likely to be something with shell command I am using (I think).

Comment: Where is the file `myproj.log` referenced?  Can you set your application to log to stdout instead?  The very long `command:` override seems to have some quoting problems (at the end, it's trying to parse GUnicorn options as separate commands); can you split this into an entrypoint wrapper that runs migrations and a `CMD gunicorn ...`, both in the Dockerfile, or put the extended command into a shell script rather than trying to put a quoted shell string inside a YAML string?

Comment: the problem is that your log file has been created in your local directory and then you are copying it on to your container and because of the differences between owners of the file django can't write on your log file. you should either ignore your log files in docker.ignore or move the last line of your Dockerfile.prod upper to actually include this log file